# ListBox SelectValue is null and selectindex = -1

Tags: c#, webforms, wizard

The listbox populates but can't find the selected value. It's either null or the default value (first item). Whenever I select another item, it changes to null. I did the !ispostback but still nothing. Using a wizard in asp.net/c#/sql. Any help is appreciated.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstService = (ListBox)Wizard1.FindControl("lstService");
        string s = lstService.SelectedValue.ToString();
        int s1 = lstService.SelectedIndex;

        if (s == "MarketTrack Toys")
        {
            Wizard2.Visible = true;
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }

        if ((Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex <= 5) && (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex != 0))
        {
            Wizard1.DisplaySideBar = true;
            Wizard2.DisplaySideBar = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Wizard1.DisplaySideBar = false;
            Wizard2.DisplaySideBar = true;
        }

    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {

        dAS = new DataAccessClass();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        ds = dAS.func_FillDataset("select servicename from dbo.Services", "Services");
        ListBox lstService = (ListBox)Wizard1.FindControl("lstService");
        lstService.DataSource = ds;
        lstService.DataTextField = "ServiceName";
        lstService.DataValueField = "ServiceName";
        lstService.DataBind();

        if (lstService.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            lstService.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're performing a `FindControl` to get a list named `lstService` into a variable, but you're not using that `lstbox` variable anywhere, and instead using `lstService`. What is `lstService`? What is the "Wizard" you are using?

Comment: lstService is the name of the listBox. The wizard I am using is Wizard1. Wizard2 is another seperate wizard. I've changed the current code accordingly (as shown above)

Comment: in addition, when i click the next button, lstService.items.count is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Walk it through in a debugger.

Whatever Object that is being placed in the ListBox doesn't know to convert itself to the string you're looking for with `ToString()`

The ListBox populates correctly because you specify how to get the names with `lstService.DataTextField = "ServiceName";`

You may have to rework the object you're putting in the ListBox or just override to ToString for that object instead.